# Images Displayed On Xcode Simulator but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am using spritekit for my app, and when I run the application on the simulator, it worked fine.  It is when I put it on a physical device that it doesn't work.  The background image, level completion image, and other key images do not show up.  As far as I can tell, everything is named correctly with the correct capitalization.  Please help!

Here is the code for the implementation of the background image:

```
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background"];
[self addChild:background];
```